# Pairwise independence of linear combination of bivariate normal distributed variables.

Tags: normal-distribution, independence

How can I show that if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent random variable having a common distribution function $F$, then linear combinations of $X_1$ and $X_2$ are pairwise independent if and only if $F$ is a normal distribution function?

Comment: I would not expect $4X_1+5X_2$ to be independent of $5X_1+4X_2$ whether or not $X_1$ and $X_2$ are normally distributed.  Perhaps I have misunderstood the question

Comment: You are right. I think about the case where for example we have two not equal linear combinations.